# How to resize cover images in OpenFlow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, coverflow

I'm trying to embed OpenFlow in my iPhone app, but I can't figure out how I can resize it in a landscape view with a navigation bar and a toolbar. The covers are too big and the effect is really ugly. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a multiplier to the values of the frame at the setImage function on AFItemView.m

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)newImage originalImageHeight:(CGFloat)imageHeight reflectionFraction:(CGFloat)reflectionFraction {
    float multiplier = 1.5;
    [imageView setImage:newImage];
    verticalPosition = imageHeight * reflectionFraction / 2;
    originalImageHeight = imageHeight;
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, newImage.size.width*multiplier, newImage.size.height*multiplier);
}
```